# Image inside flex parent with max-height and max-width and object-fit contain

Tags: html, css, flexbox, stretch

Image stretches if I don't use object-fit contains. Stretches in width, losing aspect ratio.

object-fit contain fixes that.

The problem is, the element itself is not contained, just the visible image. Which means if I make the image clickable, the whole element area (even outside the image) is clickable.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyysyngp/10/ (or see code below)

I just want the visible image to be clickable. This seems to work on Firefox, but not Chrome.

```css
body, html
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#media
{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #262423;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;  
}

#media_split 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

#media_image_container 
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: green;
}

#media_image 
{
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: calc(100% - 4em);
    max-width: calc(100% - 4.7em);
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#media_tv 
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='media'>

  <div id='media_split'>
  
    <div id='media_image_container'>
      <img id='media_image' src='https://i.imgur.com/F26h0tq.jpg'>
    </div>
    
    <div id='media_tv'></div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well some months later I found a solution. Just by adding "position: absolute" to #media_image the problem went away, which in my case didn't break anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In #media_image_container remove display: flex; and add text-align: center;

It will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It does remove the stretch problem. However it no longers centers vertically. I think at some point I moved to flex for a reason. The other forms of vertical centering seem hackish, like using transform. An answer that allows me to keep using flex's centering features would be better I think.